# BigQuery RegEx - Find string in between two chars but second char is optional

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have urls which will usually be formatted like:

```
https://test.com/foo/bar
```

I'd like to extract `bar` from this url. The proceeding slug will always be `foo`. However, sometimes url parameters might be present, like:

```
https://test.com/foo/bar?param1=test
```

In this case I would still just like to extract `bar` and not include the parameters. So essentially I'd like to get everything in between `foo/` and `?` but the `?` character is not guaranteed to be there. I've tried with this regex: `/foo/(.*?)\?` and it works well in cases where the url parameters aren't present but it includes the parameters when they are.

Is there a regex I can use that will find a string between two other strings but the second string isn't always going to be present?

Comment: Maybe you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): [`foo\/([^\s?]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/GaYBLV/1) (adjust further to your needs)

Comment: Yeah, or `/foo/([^?/#]*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex replacement approach:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(url, r'.*/|\?[^?]+', '') AS bar
FROM yourTable;
```

The regex used here says to match:

- `.*/` all content from the start of the URL up to and including the last `/`
- `|` OR
- `\?[^?]+` an optional trailing query parameter

The replacement is empty string, effectively stripping off these matches leaving behind what you want.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I would still just like to extract `bar` and not include the parameters. So essentially I'd like to get everything in between `foo/` and `?` but the `?` character is not guaranteed to be there. I've tried with this regex: `/foo/(.*?)\?` and it works well in cases where the url parameters aren't present but it includes the parameters when they are. ..."*

Since one of matching values is always the last value of the string, use the `$` to anchor any adjacent syntax.

I'm using the *global* and *multi-line* modifiers here.

```
foo/([^?]+$|.+?(?=\?))
```

This will capture anything after the first `foo/` and up to, either a `?` or the end of the line.

Here are some example captures.

Input

```
https://test.com/foo/bar
https://test.com/foo/bar?param1=test
https://test.com/foo/foo/bar/bar?param1=test
```

Output

```
bar
bar
foo/bar/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select url, 
  replace(if(starts_with(val, '/foo/'), val, ''),'/foo/', '') as result
from your_table, unnest([`bqutil.fn.cw_url_extract_path`(url)]) as val
```

if applied to sample data like in your question - output is

[image]